# Having issues installing Kali Linux in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux

Trying to install Kali Linux in VB and it freezes. I believe I have the correct version and a good ISO because it comes up and allows me to navigate to "install"

Once I press enter, all that happens is the options disappear, the Kali Linux logo remains, and nothing else happens. I've left it for hours and it just stays.

I'm running VB on an HP Laptop. I have already enabled virtualization from the BIOS, but to seemingly no avail. I have allotted 2GB of memory and 16GB of storage, along with 2 processors. I must be missing another setting because I feel that it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

One time I believe for FreeBSD I had to set the disk to static rather than dynamic sizing and that fixed some issue. Maybe try that? There's not many other options during the virtual box set up that I can think of. Maybe you have a 32 bit system and a 64 bit iso? Try getting another iso.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jacob Minshall. Do check the Host System-Architecture.
Most probably choose ISO of similar architecture.
 If both the Host and Virtual Machines are having same x86 or x86_64 bit architecture and still you are facing the issue, then kindly select the enable PAE on settings of the VB as shown in the snapshot below (in snapshot it is not selected kindly click and enable).

[image: Snapshot of Kali Virtual Box]

Answer (score 0):

For others that may have run into this, as I do not yet see an answer, what is your host OS? Windows 8 perhaps? I ran into the same for many *nix VM's in virtual box and finally discovered that I had outsmarted myself and introduced a conflict.

In playing with Win8 I was playing with Hypervisor which I enabled, created VM's, etc., before going to Virtual Box which I enjoy more. Leftover adapter garbage from Hypervisor remained and was the cause of the conflict. I turned off Hypervisor (Windows features) and all my woes have gone away. Have Kali, CentOS, Mint, and even a few different Win flavors setup as VM with no issues for any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I trying to virtualize anything in my gnu-linux environment. If your host OS is a *nix distribution (I tried with OpenSuse, Lubuntu and Arch linux), you might have the same problem as me. The solution for me at the time was to use [Gnome boxes](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Boxes), which uses a different virtualization stack than Virtual box, using libvirt and qemu. You can check a libvirt/qemu/kvm vs Vbox in [this another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203509/linux-kvm-qemu-virtualbox-vmware).